# How to wipe out work done on a feature branch by moving the head pointer?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a coworker who wants to effectively "wipe out" his changes on a feature branch and put the HEAD commit of another branch on top.  This is because his feature branch has become so stale with regards to every other branch that has been created.  He will then merge aspects of his code, which he has saved off, back into this feature branch.  I think we're trying to avoid creating another branch here.

I'm dubious of this approach.  Maybe I shouldn't be.  In any case, this isn't a rebase or merge, it's not even cherry picking.  I think what I want to do (I don't know if this is what I want to do, BTW, you guys tell me), is to change the branch pointer of this feature branch, but the HEAD exists in another branch and isn't part of this feature branch.

We use EGit in Eclipse & Gitlab if that is relevant information.

Comment: It sounds like he just wants to discard his feature branch and start a new one, which seems like a perfectly sane workflow.

Comment: Is the feature branch you reference your coworker's local branch? A branch that no one else is working on? Is the feature branch a branch off of master, or some other branch?

Answer (score 0):

Branches in git are cheap, and you can create them locally without every pushing them to the server if you are worried about filling the server with cruft.

First, start by running

```
git checkout -b <backup-branch-name>
```

to save the current branch, just in case you want to recover it later. (This will not push the branch to the server, and you can use `git branch -d <backup-branch-name>` later when you decide you don't want it anymore)

Next, checkout the original branch and run

```
git reset --hard <master-branch-name>
```

to wipe out all changes and get back in sync with your master branch (or whichever one you are using).

If your co-worker decides that they want a few of the original commits, they can use

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

to apply the changes in that commit overtop the new branch.

Finally, since you've effectively totally changed the history of the current branch, you won't be able to use a standard `git push`. You'll need to use

```
git push --force
```

which will really mess things up if anyone else has done work on this branch. In your case, sounds like that won't be a problem, but proceed with extreme caution. Cleaning up after a botched `push --force` is time-consuming and ugly.